# jQuery: insert spaces at the end of an html string

Tags: jquery, html, whitespace

I know that it is better to manage spacing by means of css rules, but how can I insert spaces between word using jQuery? Consider the following script ([see it](https://jsfiddle.net/gvhw62vq/5/) on JSfiddle) that does not work as expected (spaces are not inserted):

html:

```
<div id='div1'>
<span>hello</span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("<span>my</span> &nbsp;").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(0));
$("<span>friends</span> &nbsp;").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(1));
alert($("#div1").html());
```

Comment: What points against using padding? I know you said you know its better to use CSS. But why you need to print spaces? The trick would be &nbsp; to force showing spaces

Answer (score 3):

It will be easier if you use `append`:

```js
$("#div1").append(
    '&nbsp;',
    $('<span>').text('my'),
    '&nbsp;',
    $('<span>').text('friends'),
    '&nbsp;'
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
<span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `.before()` to insert a space:

```
$("<span>my</span>").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(0)).before("&nbsp;")
$("<span>friends</span>").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(1)).before("&nbsp;")
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/c798vsn3/2/**

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$("<span>my</span> &nbsp;")
```

creates a span element without the ending space like you can see in the following snippet.

You can reduce all chaining to one line:

```
$("<span>&nbsp;my&nbsp;</span>")
  .insertAfter($("#div1 span:first")).append($("<span>friends&nbsp;</span>"));
```

```js
console.log('Test: -->' + $("<span>my</span> &nbsp;")[0].outerHTML + '<--')

$("<span>&nbsp;my&nbsp;</span>").insertAfter($("#div1 span:first")).append($("<span>friends&nbsp;</span>"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='div1'>
    <span>hello</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with JS but with HTML, you're adding spaces outside of the span element, which has no effect. If you add the space (a regular space will work, entity name is not needed) in the span element, it'll work.

Besides that, you can clear up your code a bit if you use the JQuery append() method. This will also make it so the sentence is in one span element.

```
<span id="text">hello</span>
<script>
  $("#text").append(" my");
  $("#text").append(" friends");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("<span>&nbsp;my</span>").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(0));
$("<span>&nbsp;friends</span>").insertAfter($("#div1").children("span").eq(1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1'>
<span>hello</span>
</div>
```

I updated [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gvhw62vq/6/).

You simple have to move the `&nbsp;`